# Objective C concept explanation

Tags: objective-c

I have the following code: 
`- (void)setItem:(Todo *)newItem {
    item = newItem; }`

Why is it that I can't do 
`- (void)setItem:(Todo *)newItem {
    self.item = newItem; }` ?

I have item declared in my header file but I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error? Item is also not synthesized. The method is meant to be a custom setter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`self.item = newItem;` will cause an infinite loop since it's calling `setItem`.

Answer (score 1):

'self.item' means 'the property called item', not the variable called item (unlike Java or C#). Just use 'item = newItem;'. And don't forget to retain it if necessary!